# Salvar foto na Galeria do Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-1, silverlight

Estou usando o seguinte código para salvar a imagem no IsolateStorage:

```
String tempJPEG = "/Shared/Media/card.jpg";
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(tempJPEG))
    {
        myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
    }
    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);
    Extensions.SaveJpeg(bmp, fileStream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

E esse código para tentar salvar a imagem na galeria:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("/Shared/Media/card.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {

        MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        mediaLibrary.SavePicture("SavedCard.jpg", fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Mas quando tento rodar o app, ele fecha e no Visual dá esse erro:
[image: erro]

Estou há dias tentando resolver esse prolema. Eu encontrei um exemplo, porém ele usa imagem do próprio projeto, logo fica fácil, no meu caso a imagem é do projeto, porém é editada pelo usuário e salva no IsolateStorage..

Comment: Não conheço isto mas o erro indica que o usuário não tem acesso ao local. Não parece ser problema no código a não ser o fato de não lidar com a exceção.

Comment: Não sei exatamente porque o erro, no código que eu vi a imagem era original do app, e existe uma pasta de SD Card ou Telefone onde o app fica armazenado, e mesmo salvando essa imagem lá dá o mesmo erro, logo, não creio que seja o problema de permissão.. Muito estranho isso rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro acontece quando você não dar a permissão do aplicativo acessar a galeria de imagens.

Primeiro, vá em
Propities > WMAppManifest.xml

[image: WMAppManifest.xml]

Se for para 8.1, também tem que habilitar em Package.appxmanifest

[image: Package.appxmanifest]

Comment: Valeu muito mano, fiz um teste aqui em um novo app e funcionou, espero que quando for implantar no app que eu queria implantar funcione! Já tinha desistido, tinha tirado o recurso do app e publicado ele na loja, mas valeu kk vou implantar nele e se funcionar vou atualizar ele na loja.

Comment: de nada, boa sorte com seu app :D